# Masked domain forwarding with Yahoo domain name does not work for AWS-hosted Wordpress website (although unmasked does work). How can I fix this?

Tags: amazon-web-services, url, amazon-ec2, url-routing, yahoo-api

I'm trying to set up masked domain forwarding with a domain name bought from Yahoo for a Wordpress website that is hosted on AWS. The unmasked forwarding works, but I need it to be masked so that the actual website URL (e.g. "www.xyz.com") shows and not the public IP (elastic IP) (e.g. "1.10.10.1"). When I try to select 'masked', the website does not load - it just shows a blank white page.

I've done everything in this link: https://help.smallbusiness.yahoo.net/s/article/SLN17956

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: How is the wordpress site hosted on aws?  EC2?  Lightsail? Something is probably setting an X-FRAME-OPTIONS header for security reasons (to stop "click jacking").  But this header stops iframes from working and masked forwarding will fail (since it uses iframes).  Can you simply point the domain directly to AWS and not use forwarding at all?  Might be a better solution.

Comment: @peekay It's hosted with EC2. Do you know how to point the domain directly? I don't seem to see an option for that with the Yahoo domain manager.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how Yahoo's domain manager works.  Are you using the Bitnami Wordpress EC2 AMI?  Usually Wordpress on EC2 uses Apache as the web server. You can adjust the X-FRAME-OPTIONS header on the server.  See [this thread](https://community.bitnami.com/t/enable-wordpress-instance-to-be-displayed-in-an-iframe/55643) for an example.